# JPA entity: get the hours,minutes and sec from Oracle DATE column

Tags: java, jpa

I have problems to get the full DATE info from my Oracle DB (dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss).

In the db level, in the column that I want to receive I set test values:

```
update my_table
set my_date_column=(to_date('2011-06-15 15:43:12', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

but in my JPA entity I have:

```
@Column(name = "MY_DATE_COLUMN")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateDetailed;


public Date getDateDetailed() {
    if (this.dateDetailed!= null) {
        return this.dateDetailed;
    }
    return null;
}

public void setDateDetailed(Date dateDetailed) {
    if (dateDetailed!= null) {
        this.dateDetailed= dateDetailed;
    } else {
        this.dateDetailed= null;
    }
}
```

Each time I acccess my object, It is giving me date without hours, min and seconds.

I tried to use TemporalType.TIMESTAMP, but in that case I would need to also change column type in db (which I want to avoid).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the `TemporalType.DATE` 
You will need TIME or TIMESTAMP. DATE is only the date without time. TIMESTAMP is represented as a number.

Comment: TemporalType.DATETIME is not valid javax.persistence.TemporalType type. Only valid ones are DATE, TIME and TIMESTAMP. If I use TIMESTAMP then I must change type of column in my db to be also TIMESTAMP instead of DATE, and I would like to avoid th at if it is possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will need to do that regardless.  If you create an Oracle column of type DATE, it will not store the time information along with the date, e.g., `create table foo (bar date);`.  If you create this table and then perform the insert you mentioned, you will notice that the time information was removed and the column only contains `15-JUN-2011` rather than the expected `15-JUN-11 03.43.12.000000000 PM` (as seen from sql dev output).  The DB column must be able to support the data in order for JPA to provide the needed functionality.

Comment: @Kris In this case, can you explain me why, if in the DATE column I can only store date, my select is giving me real value including hours, minutes and seconds? And also why, with column type DATE, with EJB2 entity bean I can retrieve hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: That is an interesting question. What is the exact column definition that is being used in the table?  I have tested this scenario as I described above in an Oracle 10g db and see the result as described.  If you are truly getting the results you describe, then simply converting the JPA annotation from `TemporalType.DATE' to `TemporatlType.TIMESTAMP` should work for your particular case without any database modification.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm its written taht in DATE type we can store date AND time. My sqls from the question post are able to set/receive time from this column. And just changing TemporalType.DATE' to TemporatlType.TIMESTAMP is giving me deployment exception : wrong column type. Maybe the problem is that in select my_column which is type DATE is by default just giving me date, and default select my_column which is type TIMESTAMP is giving me both DATE and TIME..

Comment: Ok I found solution... Problem was coming that default SELECT statement with column type DATE is just returning date, and default SELECT statement for column type TIMESTAMP is returning date and time... In my case just modifying TemporalType.DATE to TemporalType.TIMESTAMP causes deployment exception because in db column type is DATE and not TIMESTAMP.. So I needed to also change column type in DB to be TIMESTAMP... Now im getting both date and time :) THanks.

Answer (score 2):

By using the TIMESTAMP temporal type, you will get the date and the time part of the java date datatype but Oracle will make a column with the TIMESTAMP datatype. To overcome this issue if you want a DATE datatype, you can use the columnDefinition parameter of the column annotation such as:

```
@Column(name = "MY_DATE_COLUMN", columnDefinition = "DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateDetailed;
```