# mysql datetime mapped to JPA Temporal.Type TIMESTAMP. Getting only date, no time in JSON response

Tags: mysql, json, datetime, jpa, resteasy

Here is scenario.

I have a JPA entity class with the field

> `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`
>   `@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE", length = 19)`
>   `private Date createdDate = null;`

And this field is mapped to a column CREATED_DATE with the type `datetime` (i am using mysql) in a Table. 
When I `select` the rows of the table, CREATED_DATE column shows the Date and Time both. When I fetch the row data using `query.getSingleResult`  and typecast the returned object to the Entity class, the `createdDate` field of the entity class also has both Date and Time :

```
request = (MyEntityClass) query.getSingleResult();<br>
System.out.println(request.getCreatedDate());
```

prints `2012-05-18 06:32:57.0` in the catalina.out log.

Now I am sending this Entity Class object to a particular client request as a Json object. The Json response the client receives though, when printed, does not show date time, it shows only date:

```
ClientResponse<String> response = clientRequest.get(String.class);
System.out.println("Response getResource ::"+response.getStatus()+"::"+response.getEntity());
```

console output: 
`Response getResource ::200::[{ ....... ,"createdDate":"18-05-2012", ......}]`
I am using RestEasy Json api at the server side.

I have seen a similar question ( [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347532/jpa-entity-get-the-hours-minutes-and-sec-from-oracle-date-column)) in SO, but the answer discussed there doesn't seem to work with me.

Please help.

Comment: The problem is related to the way the object is serialized to JSON. That is what you should describe in your question.

Comment: I am not explicitly serializing any object. What should I do now to rectify this?

Comment: The object doesn't become a JSON string automagically. You at least configured, via some annotation or config file, the framework to serialize it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JBNizet . I had to change a MessageBodyWriter class, which had set default date format to "dd-MM-yyyy" . If you could please add your above comment as an answer, I will accept the answer and comment with my code change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the way the object is serialized to JSON. You probably configured it in one way or another (annotation, default implementation, config file) so that dates are serialized this way.

Comment: There was a `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter` and a `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader` with a `java.text.DateFormat`  field set as "dd-MM-yyyy", just had to change it to "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss". Thank you for pointing out where the issue was.